# Convert Mongo Shell $or to PHP Syntax

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-4

I am a newbie so please have patience. I want to convert this robomongo query to mongolid query:

```
 db.getCollection('products').find({'images':{$size:0},                                    
                                            $or:[                                  
                                                {'inventory.a':{'$gt':0}},
                                                {'inventory.b':{'$gt':0}}
                                                ]
                                            })
```

Below is what I have right now which throws an error `Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $or needs an array`:

```
$products = Product::where([
                            'images' => [ '$size' => 0 ], 
                            '$or' => [ 
                                        'inventory.a' => ['$gt' => 0],
                                        'inventory.b' => ['$gt' => 0]
                                    ]
                            ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing brackets around the inner keys of `$or`:

```
$products = Product::where([
    'images' => [ '$size' => 0 ], 
     '$or' => [ 
            [ 'inventory.a' => ['$gt' => 0] ],
            [ 'inventory.b' => ['$gt' => 0] ]
     ]
]);
```

The MongoDB notation is a "list" of "objects", rather than as a "single object with multiple keys" as you notated.

When comparing to JSON, you should dump the JSON encoding to check:

```
echo json_encode($query, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

That way you can spot the differences in how you represented the structure.

Comment: thanks for this great information.You just rescued me here.

Comment: I tried this `echo json_encode($products, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`but it only echos `{}` . do you have any idea why?

Comment: Because what I am talking about is the "query" and not the result. So `$query = [ 'images' => [ '$size' => 0 ] ]; echo json_encode($query,JSON_PRETY_PRINT); $products = Product::where($query);` That's were it lives in the world.

Comment: thank you, this is another trick. Now I know how I can represent it.